# Symfony 3 / Doctrine - Get changes to associations in entity change set

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations

So I already know that I can get changes to a specific entity in the `preUpdate` lifecycle event:

```
/**
 * Captures pre-update events.
 * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $args
 */
 public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
 {
     $entity = $args->getEntity();


     if ($entity instanceof ParentEntity) {
            $changes = $args->getEntityChangeSet();
     }
 }
```

However, is there a way to also get changes for any associated Entities? For example, say `ParentEntity` has a relationship setup like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ChildEntity", mappedBy="parentEntity", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
 private $childEntities;
```

And `ChildEntity` also has:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GrandChildEntity", mappedBy="childEntity", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
 private $grandChildEntities;
```

Is there a way to get all relevant changes during the `preUpdate` of `ParentEntity`?

Comment: The associated entities themselves will have their own changes in `preUpdate`, unless the entities themselves remained the same.

Comment: @JasonRoman I realize that, however, I'd ideally like to do all the work on the `ParentEntity` instead of incrementally building from each separate `preUpdate`, which would result in a lot more code and a lot more edge-cases.

Comment: I found something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748790/symfony2-doctrine2-postpersist-on-associations maybe help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All of the associated entities from a OneToMany or ManyToMany relationships appear as a **Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection**.

Take a look at the PersistentCollection's API, it have some interesting public methods even if they are marked as INTERNAL: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php#L308

For example you can check if your collection is dirty which means that its state needs to be synchronized with the database. Then you can retrieve the entities that have been removed from the collection or inserted into it.

```
if ($entity->getChildEntities()->isDirty()) {
    $removed = $entity->getChildEntities()->getDeleteDiff();
    $inserted = $entity->getChildEntities()->getInsertDiff();
}
```

Also you can get a snapshot of the collection at the moment it was fetched from the database: `$entity->getChildEntities()->getSnapshot();`, this is used to create the diffs above.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I found this info earlier but wasn't sure it applied to my particular use case - your explanation helped clarify and expand on the concept for me - cheers!

Comment: Oh thanks! 3 years later, it saved my mental health.

Comment: This solution works perfectly.
I created a method for people ho needs it. I will post it in a full response

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to add in your listener to be able to extract the collection changeset :

```
    /**
     * @param object $entity
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPersistentCollectionsChangeSet(object $entity): array
    {
        $collectionChangeSet = [];
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
        $properties = $reflectionClass->getProperties();

        foreach ($properties as $property) {
            $property->setAccessible(true);
            $collection = $property->getValue($entity);

            if ($collection instanceof PersistentCollection) {
                $propertyName = $property->getName();

                if ($collection->isDirty()) {
                    $snapshot = $collection->getSnapshot();

                    if (count($snapshot) > 0) {
                        $collectionChangeSet[$propertyName][0] = $snapshot;
                        $collectionChangeSet[$propertyName][1] = $collection;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $collectionChangeSet;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this is not optimal, but it can do the job. You can add a version field on ParentEntiy with a timestamp, then on each related entity setter function (Child or GranChild) you need to add a line updating that parent timestamp entity. In this way each time you call a setter you will produce a change on the parent entity that you can capture at the listener.

I have used this solution to update ElasticSearch documents that need to be updated when a change happens on a child entity and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I can just do `$entity->childEntity->parentEntity` for `GrandChildEntity` and `$entity->parentEntity` for `ChildEntity` to access the relevant top level entity. Regardless, the problem remains that I'd need separate code for handling updates to the `ParentEntity`, `ChildEntity` and `GrandChildEntity`, as oppose to handling it all in the `ParentEntity` update event (and ignoring the other associated update events).